# SearchView, мигание клавиатуры

Tags: android, android-search-view, searchview

В моём приложении есть 2 фрагмента.
Первый фрагмент - это обычный список с `serchView` в тулбаре. `SerchView` добавлен через меню:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

Код в первом фрагменте:

```
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        setupToolbarMenu()
    }

    private fun setupToolbarMenu() {
        viewDataBinding.toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu)
        val searchItem = viewDataBinding.toolbar.menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
        searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                query?.let { viewModel.search(it) }
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        })

        searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(object : MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener {
            override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
                viewModel.search(null)
                return true
            }
        })
    }
```

Второй фрагмент отображает подробную информацию по выбранному итему из списка.

Вводим что-либо в поле поиска, переходим ко второму фрагменту, а потом возвращаемся назад. Так вот при возврате назад `searchView` забирает на себя фокус и заново открывается клавиатура. Если же скрывать клавиатуру, например, в методе `onResume()`, то при возврате происходит мигание: клавиатура открывается и мгновенно скрывается.

Как добиться такого эффекта, чтобы при возврате клавиатура не отображалась, но при этом и `serchView` оставался открытым с введённым запросом?

Comment: Возможно надо просто закрывать клавиатуру перед переходом на второй фрагмент? Чтобы оно не пыталось восстановить не нужное вам состояние при возврате на первый фрагмент

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Странно, но работает через раз. То есть один раз возвращаюсь - нет мигания, второй раз возвращаюсь - есть мигание.

Answer (score 1):

Костыльно как-то решил такую проблему давно добавив в onCreateView() фрагмента:

```
searchView.clearFocus();
```

Comment: Да, ваш способ скрывает клавиатуру, но с таким же миганием. То есть она все равно появляется и мгновенно исчезает.

Comment: @Factis Ну значит Вы где то выше в коде реквестите фокус

Comment: Это может быть связано с моим способом создания searchView? При возврате к предыдущему фрагменту каждый раз вызывается мой метод setupToolbarMenu(), возможно в этом дело?